# JavaFX 11. Как создать запускаемый jar?

Tags: java, javafx, maven, jar

Пробовал сделать через IntelliJ IDEA и Maven самостоятельно. Безрезультатно... Стандартными средствами идеи не получилось сделать, так как JDK 11 убрали модуль с JavaFX, соответственно упаковщик для него тоже. В результате начал мучать Maven. Вот мой pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>mavenproject</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenProject</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Компилирую командой:

```
compile exec:java
```

Пробовал создавать jar через:

```
clean package assembly:single
```

Comment: Самый простой способ - через мавен. Укажите подробнее, что вы делали и что не получалось?

Comment: Плз врайт рашшан

Comment: Несколько вариантов - тут: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven

Comment: У меня та же проблема. Подскажите, Вы какой командой создаёте jar? (mvn package?)
В Вашем листе для одного плагина в качестве mainClass указан Main, а для другого - MainLauncher - это опечатка?

Comment: @ПётрЛесков можно использовать mvn package. Класс Main указан в качестве mainClass в плагине для компилятора (по идее в нем также можно указать класс MainLauncher). MainLauncher нужно указывать в плагинах, касающихся непосредственно создания jar. Также посмотрите видео, указанное в начале моего ответа, там должны быть ответы на все вопросы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

И месяца не прошло, я наконец нашел ответ. Все изложено в [этом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_PsCNqqcE4&t) видео. Создается данный файл с помощью следующего плагина:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <transformers>
                <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <mainClass>MainLauncher</mainClass>
                </transformer>
            </transformers>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Стоит обратить внимание, что в тэге  нужно указать лаунчер, а не сам главный класс. Допустим наш главный класс - Main. Тогда код лаунчера выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class MainLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

Это очень важный момент, т.к. без этого jar не захочет запускаться (собственно, у меня была проблема именно с этим, потому что данный плагин я пробовал уже неоднократно).Дальше наш джарник запускаем либо через java -jar, либо обычным двойным кликом.

Вот мой pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vladhuk</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>MainLauncher</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: А exe файл не пробовал создать?

Comment: @golubtsoff Пробовал. С помощью launch4j.

Answer (score 2):

В IntelIJ с помощью комбинации клавиш CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S попадаем в структуру проекта.
Заходим в пункт Artifacts 
Нажимаем на Add (зеленый плюс), выбираем JAR и пункт from modules with dependencies. 
В выплывающем окне выбираем главный класс. Жмем ОК, закрываем окно. Выскочит еще одно окно, в котором нажимаем Apply, закрываем это окно. Настройка закончена.
Идем в пункт Build Выбираем Build Artifact, затем Build.

Исполняемый файл будет сгенерирован в директории out / Artifacts. Могут возникнуть проблемы если в проекте есть import какого-либо пакета. но этого импорта нет в classpath  Если JAR не запускается, войдите в структуру проекта, пункт Modules -> Dependencies -> Add -> Project Libruary -> Attach JAR

Если вдруг Ваше приложение консольное, и Вы хотите запускать его не через консоль, нужно будет создать bat-файл в котором прописать следующую команду

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

И запускать уже файл.bat.

Попробуйте добавить следующий код в pom.xml (Измените под себя)

```
      <build>
          <plugins>
             <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
             <archive>
             <manifest>
        <mainClass>полный.путь.к.главному.классу</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Я уже пробовал описанным способом, при запуске jar просто ничего не происходит. Полагаю, раньше (пока в Java 11 не убрали JavaFX) это легко делалось через javafxpackager . Сейчас же, если выбрать выбрать Artifacts->JavaFx Application, сборка выдает ошибку. Теперь ищу альтернативные пути.

Comment: @ВладГуковский Добавил еще один способ.

Comment: Проверьте в манифесте вашего jar-ника указан ли Main-Class:

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Не получилось. Выложил свой pom.xml, и то, как я пробовал запускать.

Comment: @VladislavHookovskii 
Тут <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
Нужно указать полный путь к файлу с главным классом. У вас просто название главного класса... На всякий случай, проверьте еще галочку Build on make в том окне, где Apply нужно нажать

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Если полный путь это D:\..., то не помогает. Main у меня не лежит также ни в каком пакете. Build on make нету в окне Artifacts (если я правильно понял, то на его месте сейчас Include in project build, который тоже не дает результата).

Comment: @Vladislav Hookovski Если Вы вытащили файл с классом на рабочий стол, то полный путь — системный диск:\\Users\имя_вашего компьютера\Desktop\Main.java.

Comment: @Vladislav Hookovski Если Ваш проект находится на GitHub, например, или еще где-то в интернете, то полный путь к главному классу — ссылка. Где-то же он храниться должен))) И когда найдете полный путь к файлу, в кавычки его возьмите.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Вообще не поддается) Впрочем, проблема судя по всему довольно новая, и скоро, думаю, начнут появляться решения в сети. Собственно мне оно сейчас не горит)